# How to bind Knockout Observable in MVC Application

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mvc

I am Using Knockout with MVC and want to display the text which can be change at run time, My Application is showing me the data which I am giving in the coding section i.e. static data but as I change the data in textbox it's not providing any result.

My code is as follows:-

**Model Class**

```
using PerpetuumSoft.Knockout;
using PerpetuumSoft;
using DelegateDecompiler;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace MvcApplication20.Models
{
 public class Class1
{

    public string Buyer { get; set; }
    public string Car { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }

    [Computed]
    public string user
    {
        get { return Buyer + " you buyed " + Car; }
        }
  }
}
```

**Controller Class**

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MvcApplication20.Models;
using PerpetuumSoft.Knockout;

namespace MvcApplication20.Controllers
{
 public class HomeController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    { 
        return View(new Class1
        {
            Buyer = "Anubhav",
            Car = "Verna",
            Price = "12 lakh"
        });
}

}
}
```

**View Class**

```
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout-2.3.0.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>
@using PerpetuumSoft.Knockout
@model MvcApplication20.Models.Class1   
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Index";
  Layout = "~/Views/ViewPage1.cshtml";
  var ko = Html.CreateKnockoutContext();
}
 <p>Buyer name: @ko.Html.TextBox(m => m.Buyer)</p>
 <p>Car name: @ko.Html.TextBox(m => m.Car)</p>
 <h2>Hello, @ko.Html.Span(m => m.user)!</h2>

 @ko.Apply(Model)
```

It's showing me the values which are given in the coding but when changing at run time then it's not updating it's value.

Comment: Where is your Knockout view model?

Comment: @PWKad This is [knockout-mvc](http://knockoutmvc.com/HelloWorld).  All of the code is auto-generated.  Downside is that this seems somewhat difficult to troubleshoot why values don't update, if the developer doesn't quite fully understand javascript, the knockout library, or what code gets generated.  I would suggest opening up developer tools in your browser and to take a look at the `viewModel` object.

Comment: Oh...  First rule of learning Knockout is don't use Knockout-MVC.  Not trying to be rude but it is trash and hacky.

Comment: I thought I had the answer for you yesterday, but I noticed it did not affect my working solution.  It might work in yours though.  Try changing your controller to extend KnockoutController.  There is documentation [HERE](http://knockoutmvc.com/Home/Documentation) saying it is needed, but you can do either way. On a side note, I used VS 2012 and .Net 4.5 to get this to work for all their examples.  Play around with jQuery and KOMVC.js versions.  I don't have the code here so I don't know what versions worked, but I had to switch them out to get a working version.